# Multiples styles in ReactJS inline style

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In plain html/css you could do something like `<div class="responsive-image placeholder">`, using the both CSS classes.
How to put two or more classes together using JSX and inline JS CSS?

Comment: You can also use multiple classes in JSX...? `<div className="responsive-image placeholder"></div>`

Comment: Yes @Mathletics, but when the class are JavaScript writed, it must be refered with <div style={someObj>

Comment: Why would you write classes in JS? Put them in the stylesheet where they belong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution for this can be:

```
function join(){
    var res={};
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; ++i)
        if (arguments[i])
            Object.assign(res,arguments[i]);
    return res;
}

var myComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div style={join(styles.a,styles.b)}>
                My Content
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var styles = {
    b: {
        fontFamily: 'roboto',
        fontSize: 13,
        backgroundColor: '#edecec',
        overflow: 'auto'
    },
    a: {
        textDecoration: 'none',
        lineHeight: 1.4,
        color: '#5e5e5e',
    }
};
```

An even more simple way:

```
var myComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div style={$.extend({},styles.a,styles.b)}>
                My Content
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Pro-tip: don't put styles in JS.

Comment: @Mathletics it's a common practice in [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html)

Comment: @Mathletics By true, I'm not liking this way too... I'm just studying and practicing with ReactJs.

Answer (score 0):

Using es6 from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign.

```js
<div style={Object.assign(stylea, styleb)}></div>
```

Comment: Much more clean solution! Thanks @janaka-stevens.